# Trailing chars in Pandas Series - How to make the sign suffix a prefix?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Series set that contains negative values using a trailing minus, like that: `1.22-`.
I want to change those in an elegant and performant way to: `-1.22`.

How can I do that.

I have tried this:

```
In [1]: pd.Series(['1.22-', '-9.99', np.nan]).str.replace('-$', '-^')
```

Which results in that:

```
Out[1]:
0       1.22-^
1       -9.99
2       NaN
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do it this way:

```
negatives = series.str[-1] == '-'
series[negatives] = '-' + series[negatives].str[:-1]
```

Comment: Worked nicely! Thanks!

Comment: Actually, what I saw in execution was a warning, I am not sure how that affects me:

```SettingWithCopyWarning: 
  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
  
  See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
    column[negatives] = '-' + column[negatives].str[:-1]

-- Docs: http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/warnings.html```